# geom_text how to position the text on bar as I want?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I would like to adjust the text on the barplot.

I tried to adjust hjust/vjust to display as I like it but it seems like it's not working properly.

```
ggplot(data) + 
        geom_bar(aes(name, count, 
        fill = week), stat='identity', position = 'dodge') +
        geom_text(aes(name,count, 
        label=count),hjust=0.5, vjust=3, size=2,
        position = position_dodge(width = 1)) + 
        coord_flip()
```

[image]

So I would like the numbers to situate on each bar, in the middle, at the right-edge so it's readable without overlapping like the last parts.

Comment: You need to include enough data [to make your example reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

### Edit:

The easier solution to get `hjust`/`vjust` to behave intelligently is to add the `group` aesthetic to `geom_text` and then `hjust` & `position` adjust for the `group` automatically.

## 1. Vertical Orientation

```
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_bar(
    aes(x = name, y = count, fill = week, group = week), 
    stat='identity', position = 'dodge'
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = name, y = count, label = count, group = week),
    position = position_dodge(width = 1),
    vjust = -0.5, size = 2
  ) + 
  theme_bw()
```

This gives:

[image]

## 2. Horizontal Orientation

```
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_bar(
    aes(x = name, y = count, fill = week, group = week), 
    stat='identity', position = 'dodge'
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = name, y = count, label = count, group = week), 
    hjust = -0.5, size = 2,
    position = position_dodge(width = 1),
    inherit.aes = TRUE
  ) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_bw()
```

This gives:

[image]

---

This is not necessarily the most general way to do this, but you can have a `fill` dependent `hjust` (or `vjust`, depending on the orientation) variable. It is not entirely clear to me how to select the value of the adjustment parameter, and currently it is based on what *looks* right. Perhaps someone else can suggest a more general way of picking this parameter value.

## 1. Vertical Orientation

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# generate some data
data = data_frame(
  week = as.factor(rep(c(1, 2), times = 5)),
  name = as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:5], times = 2)),
  count = rpois(n = 10, lambda = 20),
  hjust = if_else(week == 1, 5, -5),
  vjust = if_else(week == 1, 3.5, -3.5)
)

# Horizontal
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_bar(
    aes(x = name, y = count, fill = week, group = week), 
    stat='identity', position = 'dodge'
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = name, y = count, label = count, vjust = vjust), 
    hjust = -0.5, size = 2,
    inherit.aes = TRUE
  ) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_bw()
```

Here is what that looks like:

[image]

## 2. Horizontal Orientation

```
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_bar(
    aes(x = name, y = count, fill = week, group = week), 
    stat='identity', position = 'dodge'
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = name, y = count, label = count, vjust = vjust), 
    hjust = -0.5, size = 2,
    inherit.aes = TRUE
  ) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_bw()
```

Here is what that looks like:

[image]

Comment: This is definitely the outlook I ultimately like to create, but when I apply this on my work, it returns Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'vjust' not found. how does vjust=vjust work? what's the logic behind this?

Comment: @silverrain Did you update the dataset using the code that I have given? You will need to create a new variable in your dataset called `vjust`/`hjust`that contains the `fill` variable dependent adjustment value. Having said all that, that would be required for this version solution, but I am going to update the solution so that it becomes much easier to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much! I checked the vjust/hjust after your comments, and was wondering how to automate it! The grouping option is really smart and efficient I think! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The best answer I have found, so far. Nice one!

Answer (score 14):

The `position_dodge()` statement takes a width parameter. To ensure that the text is centred at the end of the bars (i.e., the dodging width for the bars and the text to be the same), give the same width parameter to the `position_dodge()` statement within `geom_bar` and within `geom_text`.

There is also a width parameter for `geom_bar`, that is the width of the bars. If you want the bars to butt up against each other within each `name`, make the bar width the same as the dodging width; if you want a small gap between the bars, make the bar width a little less than the dodging width.

If you use global aesthetics, you will not need a `group` aesthetic (however, using only local aesthetics, you will need a group aesthetic for `geom_text`).

`hjust = -0.5` will position the text labels just beyond the end of the bars; `hjust = 1.5` positions them inside the end of the bars.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Generate some data - using @tchakravarty's data - Thanks.
df = data.frame(
  week = as.factor(rep(c(1, 2), times = 5)),
  name = as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:5], times = 2)),
  count = rpois(n = 10, lambda = 20))

position = position_dodge(width = .75)
width = .75

ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = count, label = count, fill = week)) + 
  geom_bar(width = width, stat='identity', position = position) +
  geom_text(hjust = -0.5, size = 2, position = position) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_bw()



# To separate the bars slightly:
position = position_dodge(width = .75)
width = .65

ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = count, label = count, fill = week)) + 
  geom_bar(width = width, stat='identity', position = position) +
  geom_text(hjust = -0.5, size = 2, position = position) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: This is very efficient and way quicker to plot the chart! Thank you @sandy-muspratt