# R Change position of text in geom_bar()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a bar-plot with `geom_text()`. Above every bar should be the count of the variable. But in this case the position of the text is in the middle of the barplot.
Can someone help me to solve this problem?

```
new.data <- diamonds[ which( diamonds$clarity =="VS1" | diamonds$clarity =="VS2") , ]

ggplot(data=new.data, aes(x=clarity, fill=cut)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "count") +
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1)
```

[image]

Comment: add `position = position_dodge(width = 1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017460/position-geom-text-on-dodged-barplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the `position` argument like mentioned in the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211451/geom-text-how-to-position-the-text-on-bar-as-i-want)

```
new.data <- diamonds[ which( diamonds$clarity =="VS1" | diamonds$clarity =="VS2") , ]

ggplot(data=new.data, aes(x=clarity, fill=cut)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "count") +
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1,
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

output:

[image: plot]

like mentioned by TobKel in the commentary, it is possible to variate with the width.

Comment: Yes this works. Buts it looks better with position_dodge(width = 0.9)