# Geom_Text not positioning vjust label over Geom_Bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I was following code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211451/geom-text-how-to-position-the-text-on-bar-as-i-want/56859850#56859850) but it is not working the same for me. Here's my code and screenshot below. Can you help me center the label with spacing just above the bar?

[image: Click Here - Screenshot]

```
p <- ggplot(data=mrc, aes(x = Year, y = Total, fill = Year)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(
        aes(x = Year, y = Total, label = Total),
        position = position_dodge(width = 1),
        vjust = -0.5, size = 3
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#115740","#B9975B","#D0D3D4","#F0B323")) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", colour = "#B9975B")) +
  ggtitle("Petitions") 

ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: Please share your data (`mrc`) to make it reproducible

Comment: Unrelated, but you can simplify your code by using `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")` and omitting the `position = ` argument to `geom_text`.

Comment: @neilfws Thanks for the tip mate. Why use geom_col() instead? And why omit position?

Comment: @Willy less typing :) and position makes no difference in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/769) here is `ggplotly`. One solution is to use `style(textposition = "top")`.

Recreating your data:

```
mrc <- data.frame(Year = c("2015-16", "2016-17", "2017-18", "2018-19"),
                  Total = c(225, 461, 471, 230),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Running the first section of your code to generate `p`:

```
p
```

[image]

All good. But the result using `ggplotly`:

```
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Adding `style()`:

```
ggplotly(p) %>% style(textposition = "top")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even think that ggplotly was the cause of the issue. Could you explain your thought process for finding the culprit and the solution?

Comment: @Willy I just ran the standard ggplot first, then inspected the difference after ggplotly. I guess I’ve seen previous questions where ggplotly has caused issues too, so I’m primed to be suspicious.