# geom_text label using nudge_y with reactive bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, shiny

I have a simple bar chart I am using in a shiny application with some filters. I am using the following code.

```
ggplot(users_by_month(), aes(x = month, y = n)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(label=n), nudge_y = 4)
```

When no filters are being used this works and the sum of each month is above the bar. However when I use a filter and the values change the sums above the bars move to much higher above the bar. Is there a way to keep the `nudge_y` relative to the bar height so the text remains right above the bar as the underlying data changes?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it by overriding the `y` aes with a computed derived stat (here `n + 10% of the max n`):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  group_by(length= cut(Petal.Length, seq(5))) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = length, y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=n, y=n + .1 * after_scale(max(n))))
```

[image]

```r
iris %>% 
  group_by(length= cut(Petal.Length, seq(5))) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  filter(n < 10) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = length, y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=n, y=n + .1 * after_scale(max(n))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Not seeing any labels now using `geom_text(aes(label=n, y=n + .1 * after_scale(max(n))))`, any idea why that would occur?

Answer (score 2):

We can see your problem very clearly by setting up an example that uses facets with very different ranges. There is a single `geom_text` layer with `nudge_y = 4`:

```r
df <- data.frame(month = factor(c(1:3, 1:3)), 
                 n     = c(80, 21, 45, 8, 2, 1),
                 panel = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(month, n)) +
  geom_col(fill = "deepskyblue4") +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), size = 6, nudge_y = 4) +
  facet_wrap(.~panel, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(c(0, 0.1))) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Obviously, the y axis scale is smaller on the right, so the 4-unit nudge is proportionately much greater and now doesn't sit nicely on the bars.

One way to solve this is to fix the y axis `limits`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(month, n)) +
  geom_col(fill = "deepskyblue4") +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), size = 6, nudge_y = 4) +
  facet_wrap(.~panel, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 90), expand = expansion(c(0, 0.1))) +
  ylim(c(0, 90)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

However, if you want the bars to fill the plotting area, the easiest way is probably to just use `vjust` instead of `nudge_y`. Remember, you need a *negative* `vjust` to shift the text upwards.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(month, n)) +
  geom_col(fill = "deepskyblue4") +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), size = 6, vjust = -0.5) +
  facet_wrap(.~panel, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(c(0, 0.1))) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: For some reason `vjust = -0.5` doesnt seem to be working?

Comment: Looks like it was `ggplotly` causing my issue, `style(textposition = "top")` resolved it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860019/geom-text-not-positioning-vjust-label-over-geom-bar